# Parameter for Multiple Value in column

Tags: postgresql

I don't know how to as this but, here's what I have as sample:

```
Table1
firstname          middlename              lastname
JAMIE JANE         SCOTT                   LACSON
CRYSTAL            SANTON                  TRAINEE
ANNA MARIE JOY     CAPRUTE                 PAGE
```

And i want to select only the firstname with have two or more value.

Based on the above sample, the result should be:

```
firstname          middlename              lastname
JAMIE JANE         SCOTT                   LACSON
ANNA MARIE JOY     CAPRUTE                 PAGE
```

Thanks so much!  ^_^

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty easy:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where t.firstname like '% %';
```

If `firstname` contains spaces at the beginning or end:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where trim(both ' ' from t.firstname) like '% %';
```

Comment: it should not requires particular value from the column.

Comment: @fLen . . . I have no idea what your comment refers to.  This query should do what you want.

Comment: What I need is a query that select 2 or more value or words in a column, have you seen the "should be result"? using your pretty answer is requiring particular value between %% otherwise, it will load all data in the table. If ever I missing something with your answer, please let me know. thanks

Comment: I stand corrected.. ^_^ @gordon Linoff, you're were right. I need have to put trim(firstname) to eliminate all unnecessary space in the column. thanks for the idea! :D

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question of mine, given the idea from @Gordon Linoff: Thank you!

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where trim(t.firstname) like '% %';
```

Shows result that I need.